# strtotime() is returning a 1970 date and don't comparing well to time()

Tags: php

I'm trying to convert a string that enters in my program from a `JSON` to a `date`, so I can compare it to actual time.
I'm using `strtotime()` but it converts the original date to `01/01/1970 12:00:00`.
Here's my code:

```
var_dump($requestOrder->date);
$requestDate= date('d/m/Y h:i:s', strtotime($requestOrder->date));
var_dump($requestDate);
```

Where, `date` inside the `$requestOrder` is equal to `"24/12/2021 00:00:00"`.
And here's what I'm getting:

```
string(19) "24/12/2021 00:00:00"
string(19) "01/01/1970 12:00:00"
```

I need to convert it to a `date` because, lately, in some point of my code, I do this:

```
if($requestDate< date('d/m/Y h:i:s', time())) {
    ...
}
```

I've been trying a lot of options to solve this problem, such as changing the `/` to `-`, using other formats for the date, etc, but with no luck. In the case of using a `str_replace` to change the `/` to `-`, it works and doesn't show a 70's date, but then it doesn't do the comparison well, it always detects the date smallest to actual one.
Does someone see what I'm skipping?

Comment: Read this [User Contributed Notes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php) in the official document.

Comment: `strtotime` converts a valid time string in to a timestamp nubmer, `date` format the timestamp to a string with the provided format. The format you provided for `date` does not affect `strtotime` and since `d/m/Y H:i:s` is not a valid format for `strtotime`, it returns `false`

Comment: If the format of the input is always the same, you should better use `DateTime::createFromFormat` (which is able to work with a format that `strtotime` cannot read) and work on `DateTime` objects

Comment: Also, why do you compare strings if you could better compare timestamps or proper date objects?

Comment: @NicoHaase working with strings because my code is constantly sending and receiving dates, and the way it receives it is by strings, so I found it easier to work with this format instead of spending a lot of time (and computing) converting strings to `DateTime` objects and then turning them into strings again to return it to the client. And because another condition I need to check is that the `date field` the client sends is not empty, so I use a `strlen() <= 0` in the condition, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check below code:

```
$requestOrder->date="24/12/2021 00:00:00";
$date=str_replace("/",'-',$requestOrder->date);  
if(strtotime($date)>time())
{
   //this will  execute as request date is greater than current date
}
if(strtotime($date)<time())
{
   //this will not execute as current date less than request date
}
```

Comment: Yes, this works for me to convert the string to real `dateTime` instead of 1970 date, but when doing the comparison, the program always detect is less than actual time, no matter what date I'm comparing to actual.

Comment: @FourBars in condition check we have used if(strtotime($date)<time()), it works

Comment: Date you are checking is 24/12/2021 00:00:0 and current date is 28/10/2021 so it is not going into condition, you need to use ">" to go inside condition.

Comment: Using `>` inside conditions converts all dates into valid, no matter if they're greater or slower than the actual one...

Comment: see I have changed date to lower than current 2020 year, its working 
$requestOrder->date="24/12/2020 00:00:00";
$date=str_replace("/",'-',$requestOrder->date);
if(strtotime($date)>time())
{
   echo "Here";
}

Comment: So based on your requirement apply less than or greater than. I have added code as well for lower date check.

Comment: The thing is. If I use `<` on your comparison, then the programs detect all input dates as if they were before today, no matter if they really are before or after the actual date. Then, if I use `>`, the program does the opposite, it detects all input dates like if they were after the actual date, no matter if in fact, they're before or after today.

Comment: Please share more details. What did you change, and why? Please add all clarification to your answer by editing it

Comment: @FourBars I have updated code with both condition with comment please check.

Answer (score 2):

The `date()` function [returns a string not a DateTime object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). It would be better to use the actual `DateTime` class and its `createFromFormat` function.

```php
$requestDate = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y h:i:s', $requestOrder->date);
```

or object oriented style

```php
$requestDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y h:i:s', $requestOrder->date);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Converting strings into `DateTime` object is a good option, too. But it's not what I need to do in this case, because I'm code needs to do some other comparisons that need them as `strings`. Even so, I think this answer can be useful for other users in similar situations as mine.